# No comment Section but still got a Comment

Tags: comments, blog-page

Somebody commented on my blog article, but I dont have a Comment Section on my blog. Also my blog is in german and the comment was in english. I'm not sure how this is possible and how this could happen.

Has anyone experience with this?

Comment: Can you check in the database, using phpMyAdmin, to see whether comments are enabled for the particular Post where you got a comment? I'm wondering if they may have used the REST API or some other means to add a comment since you don't have an actual form to allow comments. If you find comments are allowed, you can disable comments on all existing Posts in phpMyAdmin with a simple script.

Comment: Have you disabled comments in wp settings?

Comment: I didn't disable them, because I didn't think about them, because I have no Comment Section. Now I have all comments disabled, but I was wondering if it's possible to comment on a post with comments enabled but to section for them. I thought there may be a subpage or something, but I couldn't find anything.